# Persisting mongodb (2.0) connection through nodejs Express Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm having some trouble with a presumably simple task. I'm starting an express (4) application with the native mongodb (2) driver and looking into how to open a connection to the mongo server/db once, re-use it through the express lifetime, and close it when the express application closes.

Here's what I have so far (only showing the pertinent snippets):

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/course';

// This cannot be the correct way to do this.
//  dbClient doesn't seem to be persisting the connection
//  details when connect(...) returns;
var dbClient;
MongoClient.connect(url, {native_parser: true}, function(err,db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    dbClient = db
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // 1) How do I access the MongoDB connection at this point?
    //      Need a way to persist the connection and access it here.    
    // 2) How exaclty would I query a specific document here?
    //      Should I be working with MongoDB 'collections'
    //      and use that to find documents?
    dbClient.find({}, function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        res.render('index', doc);
    });     
});

app.listen(8000);
console.log("Listening at http://localhost:8000");
```

Comment: yes, using the MongClient, you'll have to select the collection first before you try to find something. https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

Comment: As far as persisting a connection, i'm not sure if that's a good idea or not. That will depend on whether or not the connection will handle multiple requests at a time, or if it only handles one at a time like most other db systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb does not have built in support for persistent connections. I would recommend looking into [Mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). While Mongoose does not have persistent connections it has connection pools. Which means instead of reconnecting mongodb on each request it takes one connection from the pool of reusable connections and then returns it back.As per your example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/');
var myModel = mongoose.model('course');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     myModel.find({}, function(err, doc) {
     console.log(doc);
     res.render('index', doc);
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did research Mongoose, and while it is an abstraction of the native driver, I would like to start learning and utilizing Mongo with simple web apps using the native driver. If this means I cannot persist a connection and will need to re-create one each time a route is hit in my application then that's fine. Marking this as an answer since it seems to solve the problem of at the very least giving the perception of a persisted connection, by utilizing mongoose's connection pools per request.